# Using prestashop webservices in Android

Tags: android, xml, web-services, prestashop

I have a problem with PrestaShop web services. I'm creating an Android app for one service. I configured everything in panel properly, gave corresponding permissions (e.g. GET, POST, DELETE, PUT for "carts"). When I'm sending GET request I get a response. Everything works. Problems start when I try to use e.g. DELETE, PUT or POST.
I followed this tutorial:
http://blog.belvg.com/prestashop-web-services.html
I make my test requests via site https://www.hurl.it/
Trying to update something, for instance, cart number 1 I get it by:

http:// MYDOMAIN .pl/api/carts/1?schema=synopsis

Then I edit some fields and try to send it back by PUT method and XML as the parameter, but I get:

```
<H1>400 Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Trying to add a new cart does not work also. I try it by getting blank XML:
http://MYDOMAIN.pl/api/carts?schema=blank
That gives me blank XML. When I will not fill this XML and I try to send it back by POST I get the message:

```
  <message>
    <![CDATA[Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.]]>
  </message>
```

What means possibly it can work. But when I will fill it with data, I get again 400... Any Idea what I can be doing wrong? Did I miss something?

P.S. I have access to an only panel (not server) and can do things only via panel and send requests.

Comment: Have you enabled the mod_dev in config/defines.inc.php? if done plz update your question with the error

Comment: Where are errors listed? I enabled it now.

Comment: that should be in replace of  <message>
    <![CDATA[Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.]]>
  </message>
Have you added define('DEBUG',true); also?